# Do I need to EnterWriteLock when using AddHandler?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

When using a ReadWriteLockSlim for multi-threading support, do I need to EnterWriteLock when using AddHandler?

Here are two examples to help illustrate my point:

```
AddHandler ClassInstance.Event, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.Method)
```

*-or-*

```
Me.ReaderWriterLockSlimInstance.EnterWriteLock()
AddHandler ClassInstance.Event, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.Method)  
Me.ReaderWriterLockSlimInstance.ExitWriteLock()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend on the event; for example, if you are consuming an event from a dll written in C# via a "field-like event", i.e.

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent; // synchronized
```

(yes I know you asked about VB; I explain this below...)

then this is (per the C# language spec) automatically synchronized, so there are no multi-threading issues (and it helps here that delegates are immutable). However, even in the same library, a non-field-like event might **not** be synchronized - i.e.

```
private EventHandler myField;
public event EventHandler SomeEvent { // not synchronized
    add { myField += value; }
    remove { myField -= value; }
}
```

I know you asked about VB... but you are asking about VB as the **comsumer**. My point is that it depends on the **publisher**.

So if you can't control the publisher, then manually synchronizing sounds adviseable **if** you think that there is a threading risk for this scenario (in most cases, there is no need to synchronize; but if you know this is a threaded area, then synchronizing is sensible).

Also note that a common pattern when **raising** an event is to take a snapshot:

```
protected virtual void OnSomeEvent() {
    EventHandler handler = SomeEvent; // assume the "field-like" version
    if(handler!=null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

My point *here* is that it is in theory possible for a subscriber to receive an event **even after they think they have unsubscribed**, so if extreme cases you might want to handle this manually, perhaps by keeping a flag somewhere (or just exception handling).

---

As requested, last code fragment in VB (via reflector) for comparison:

```
Protected Overridable Sub OnSomeEvent()
    Dim handler As EventHandler = Me.SomeEvent
    If (Not handler Is Nothing) Then
        handler.Invoke(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great post. You raise a very good point. In this instance my program is indeed the producer as well as the consumer. My C# is very rusty at the moment, so is there any chance you could translate the last bit of code you posted into VB.Net?